# So i want to make a bot for my discord where if i make a new post on my instagram and run the bot, it will get the new post's link and share it there

Tags: python, selenium, instagram

So, I want to get the 8th link from all the scraped links on the webpage, and here is my code.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options()
options.binary_location = '/Applications/Brave Browser.app/Contents/MacOS/Brave Browser'

PATH = '/Users/grag/chromedriver'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options = options, executable_path = PATH)

driver.get('https://instagram.com/my_username')

RecentPostLink = driver.find_element_by_tag_name('a')
elems = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@href]")
for elem in elems:
    print(elems.get_attribute("href"))
```

I don't know how I can get only the 8th link.

Answer (score 1):

```
elems
```

is a list in python, to get 8th item, you can do :

```
print(elems[7].get_attribute('href'))
```